# og:type and valid values : constantly being parsed as og:type=website

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Could someone sugggest why the FB debug/lint tool is saying og:type is "website" despite the og:type being set to og:bar?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.shamrockirishbar.com%2Fpubquiz

As a result its not validating the og:location and similar which are relevant for the "bar" type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have moved into the world of namespace specific open graph data and therefore dont rely on the FB types. See "edit open graph" in the apps dev tool dashboard.

Comment: can you provide a details to your solution. my og:type="product" and the linter says it is not the correct type

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay see my answer to this question for more details

Answer (score 31):

`bar` is deprecated. Please check [ogp.me](https://ogp.me/#types) for the current docs.

Comment: Thanks. Yet its listed in the facebook open graph supported types. In addition there is next to no info there that I can (Have I missed it). About 3 types are listed and none with relevant location data etc. So I guess this is a FB issue where Bar (and similar location type "objects") are not actually OG but FB specific?

Comment: @RichieHH that link doesn't have any info on types any more :-( New Link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph

Comment: @RichieHH Actually OpenGraph was createed by Facebook. That's one reason why they used a "properties" attribute instead of the expected "name" attribute. It should be `<meta name="og:title" content="Awesome Stuff Here"/>`.

Answer (score 27):

As of May 2018, you can find the full list here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph#object-type

> `apps.saves`   An action representing someone saving an app to try
>   later.
>
> `article`   This object represents an article on a website. It is the
>   preferred type for blog posts and news stories.
>
> `book`   This object type represents a book or publication. This is an
>   appropriate type for ebooks, as well as traditional paperback or
>   hardback books. Do not use this type to represent magazines
>
> `books.author`   This object type represents a single author of a
>   book.
>
> `books.book`   This object type represents a book or publication. This
>   is an appropriate type for ebooks, as well as traditional paperback or
>   hardback books
>
> `books.genre`   This object type represents the genre of a book or
>   publication.
>
> `books.quotes`
>   *Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.* 
> An action representing someone quoting from a book.
>
> `books.rates`
>   *Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.* 
> An action representing someone rating a book.
>
> `books.reads`
>   *Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.* 
> An action representing someone reading a book.
>
> `books.wants_to_read`
>   *Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.* 
> An action representing someone wanting to read a book.
>
> `business.business`   This object type represents a place of business
>   that has a location, operating hours and contact information.
>
> `fitness.bikes`
>   *Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.* 
> An action representing someone cycling a course.
>
> `fitness.course`   This object type represents the user's activity
>   contributing to a particular run, walk, or bike course.
>
> `fitness.runs`
>   *Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.* 
> An action representing someone running a course.
>
> `fitness.walks`
>   *Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.* 
> An action representing someone walking a course.
>
> `game.achievement`   This object type represents a specific
>   achievement in a game. An app must be in the 'Games' category in App
>   Dashboard to be able to use this object type. Every achievement has a
>   `game:points` value associate with it. This is not related to the
>   points the user has scored in the game, but is a way for the app to
>   indicate the relative importance and scarcity of different
>   achievements: * Each game gets a total of 1,000 points to distribute
>   across its achievements * Each game gets a maximum of 1,000
>   achievements * Achievements which are scarcer and have higher point
>   values will receive more distribution in Facebook's social channels.
>   For example, achievements which have point values of less than 10 will
>   get almost no distribution. Apps should aim for between 50-100
>   achievements consisting of a mix of 50 (difficult), 25 (medium), and
>   10 (easy) point value achievements Read more on how to use
>   achievements in [this guide](/docs/howtos/achievements/).
>
> `games.achieves`   An action representing someone reaching a game
>   achievement.
>
> `games.celebrate`   An action representing someone celebrating a
>   victory in a game.
>
> `games.plays`   An action representing someone playing a game. Stories
>   for this action will only appear in the activity log.
>
> `games.saves`   An action representing someone saving a game.
>
> `music.album`   This object type represents a music album; in other
>   words, an ordered collection of songs from an artist or a collection
>   of artists. An album can comprise multiple discs.
>
> `music.listens`
>   *Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.* 
> An action representing someone listening to a song, album, radio station,
>   playlist or musician
>
> `music.playlist`   This object type represents a music playlist, an
>   ordered collection of songs from a collection of artists.
>
> `music.playlists`
>   *Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.* 
> An action representing someone creating a playlist.
>
> `music.radio_station`   This object type represents a 'radio' station
>   of a stream of audio. The audio properties should be used to identify
>   the location of the stream itself.
>
> `music.song`   This object type represents a single song.
>
> `news.publishes`   An action representing someone publishing a news
>   article.
>
> `news.reads`
>   *Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.* 
> An action representing someone reading a news article.
>
> `og.follows`   An action representing someone following a Facebook
>   user
>
> `og.likes`   An action representing someone liking any object.
>
> `pages.saves`   An action representing someone saving a place.
>
> `place`   This object type represents a place - such as a venue, a
>   business, a landmark, or any other location which can be identified by
>   longitude and latitude.
>
> `product`   This object type represents a product. This includes both
>   virtual and physical products, but it typically represents items that
>   are available in an online store.
>
> `product.group`   This object type represents a group of product
>   items.
>
> `product.item`   This object type represents a product item.
>
> `profile`   This object type represents a person. While appropriate
>   for celebrities, artists, or musicians, this object type can be used
>   for the profile of any individual. The `fb:profile_id` field
>   associates the object with a Facebook user.
>
> `restaurant.menu`   This object type represents a restaurant's menu. A
>   restaurant can have multiple menus, and each menu has multiple
>   sections.
>
> `restaurant.menu_item`   This object type represents a single item on
>   a restaurant's menu. Every item belongs within a menu section.
>
> `restaurant.menu_section`   This object type represents a section in a
>   restaurant's menu. A section contains multiple menu items.
>
> `restaurant.restaurant`   This object type represents a restaurant at
>   a specific location.
>
> `restaurant.visited`   An action representing someone visiting a
>   restaurant.
>
> `restaurant.wants_to_visit`   An action representing someone wanting
>   to visit a restaurant
>
> `sellers.rates`   An action representing a commerce seller has been
>   given a rating.
>
> `video.episode`   This object type represents an episode of a TV show
>   and contains references to the actors and other professionals involved
>   in its production. An episode is defined by us as a full-length
>   episode that is part of a series. This type must reference the series
>   this it is part of.
>
> `video.movie`   This object type represents a movie, and contains
>   references to the actors and other professionals involved in its
>   production. A movie is defined by us as a full-length feature or short
>   film. Do not use this type to represent movie trailers, movie clips,
>   user-generated video content, etc.
>
> `video.other`   This object type represents a generic video, and
>   contains references to the actors and other professionals involved in
>   its production. For specific types of video content, use the
>   `video.movie` or `video.tv_show` object types. This type is for any
>   other type of video content not represented elsewhere (eg. trailers,
>   music videos, clips, news segments etc.)
>
> `video.rates`
>   *Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.* 
> An action representing someone rating a movie, TV show, episode or another piece
>   of video content.
>
> `video.tv_show`   This object type represents a TV show, and contains
>   references to the actors and other professionals involved in its
>   production. For individual episodes of a series, use the
>   `video.episode` object type. A TV show is defined by us as a series or
>   set of episodes that are produced under the same title (eg. a
>   television or online series)
>
> `video.wants_to_watch`
>   *Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.* 
> An action representing someone wanting to watch video content.
>
> `video.watches`
>   *Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.* 
> An action representing someone watching video content.

Comment: this is great. where do u see this list tho? I was looking for it everywhere. The link provided is missing some like "restaurant"

Comment: link is now dead

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old one but it comes up top of Google and all the links provided now seem out of date.

This is the latest list of types Facebook accepts for 2022:
https://ogp.me/#types

If you don't use one of these then the type will default to 'website' which is best used for home pages/summarizing a web site.

It looks like the place attribute is no longer supported and the [old Facebook page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/place/) has gone.

Comment: That list doesn't include `website`, which seems to be the type many examples use ;(

Comment: It is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#basic and still states that website is the default. Bear in mind were talking about Facebook here and stuff changes all the time.

Answer (score 3):

This started happening to my site after I enabled namespace and custom Open Graph actions and objects. Once you enable it, you lose support for standard object types such as bar, or in my case article. (or it's possible Facebook may have deprecated certain types, I'm not 100% sure)  When no supported type is specified, Facebook defaults to website.

To fix this what you need to do is go into your app dashboard, select your app, then go to the Open Graph section.  Under "Object Types", define your own types, such as "bar."

Next you will have to change your meta tags to look like this:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="your_namespace:your_object_type" />
```

If you click on "Get Code" next to the object type in the dashboard, Facebook will provide you with an example of meta tags to use.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your article:author data is a Facebook author URL.   Unfortunately, that conflicts with what Pinterest is expecting.   It's the best thing about standards, there are so many ways to implement them!

```
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/mpatnode76">
```

But Pinterest wants to see something like this:

```
<meta property="article:author" content="Mike Patnode">
```

We ended up swapping the formats depending upon the user agent.  Hopefully, that doesn't screw up your page cache.  That fixed it for us.

Full disclosure.  Found this here: https://surniaulula.com/2014/03/01/pinterest-articleauthor-incompatible-with-open-graph/